# Turn on /off the debug mode for particular controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to turn on the debug mode for particualr controller in cakephp . Now I am doing this in config/core.php ,it working fine . But it is easy to enable /disable in controller ,we can avoid probelms with working in live sites ,otherwise the log will messed up users

Answer (score 17, accepted):

its actually security critical to do anything wild like that in the core.php, it has to be and stay always 0 for ALL user frontend sites.

If you want to enable it for some admin backend action, you can do that inside the action at the very beginning with

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the party on this one but just in case anyone else needs this

```
$skdebug = 0;
if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]== '121.75.33.244') $skdebug = 2;
Configure::write('debug', $skdebug);
```

I work offsite so I'm the only user on the IP, can be a pain to have to keep updating the IP when the router decides to bounce but it's a small price to pay.

It does mean debug is on for all controllers but that's not a problem.

Comment: This is not really related to the original question, but is great for turning debug on /off based on ip address. Thansk @SarahKing for the great tip

Answer (score 2):

**It work for me in cakephp 3.4**.

Use the below code in top of your controller in cakephp 3+:

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
```

Then your `beforeFilter()` code should be something like below:

```
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event){
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler'); 

    // allow the function to public access
    $this->Auth->allow(['index','logout','register','saveOrders']);

    $actions = [
       'saveOrders','save-orders',
    ];

    // change the debug mode for a particular action
    if (in_array($this->request->params['action'], $actions)) {
       Configure::write('debug', false); // off debug mode
    }
}
```

Comment: very bad idea to switch the default mode this way, it should always be off by default.

Comment: I suggest this only for debug purpose.

Comment: Yeah, but it is the wrong way. It must be the other way: debug off by default. If action = x then debug on.