# How to switch on debug mode in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am setting `$debug` to `true` in *app.php*, but nothing changes.

How can I enable debug mode in CakePHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn on /off the debug mode for particular controller in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462231/turn-on-off-the-debug-mode-for-particular-controller-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration), you can enable or disable the debug mode by changing the value of the "debug" parameter in the config/app.php file.

```
/**
 * Debug Level:
 *
 * Production Mode:
 * false: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown.
 *
 * Development Mode:
 * true: Errors and warnings shown.
 */
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

And in your controller, you can do logging using the [log() method](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#logging-trait) (avalaible for all objects) :

```
$this->log('debug message','debug');
```

Comment: And look in logs/debug.log to see the 'debug message'

Answer (score 1):

`app_local.php` overwrites `app.php`. Look for the `'DEBUG', true` there.