# How to tell if debug mode is on in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.6

I want to know how I can retrieve the var inside of the env() function...

```
/**
 * Debug Level:
 *
 * Production Mode:
 * false: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown.
 *
 * Development Mode:
 * true: Errors and warnings shown.
 */
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

Right now I am using

```
<?php if(DEBUG == true) { ?>
```

but that is throwing an error

```
Use of undefined constant DEBUG - assumed 'DEBUG' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

Comment: see this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462231/turn-on-off-the-debug-mode-for-particular-controller-in-cakephp

Comment: That is for creating your own debug variable, I want to use the one CakePHP provides... I don't need two debug variables, that could get messy

Comment: `\Cake\Core\Configure::read('debug')`

Comment: ndm: There isn't a constant that has the debug value in it is there?

Comment: No, there isn't, changing debug mode at runtime is often required in the testing environment, and a constant wouldn't allow that. If you'd like to use a constant, then you'd have to define one yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by ndm you can use `read` method to check whether debug mode is `ON` or `OFF`.

Add this in your controller

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
```

and then use read method like this:

```
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
  echo "Debug mode is ON";
 } else {
  echo "Debug mode is OFF";
}
```

[Cakephp -> Configuration -> Reading Configuration Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-configuration-data)

Answer (score 0):

By `Configure::read(key)` you can find out.

Please check following link:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-configuration-data